# Two rows into two columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this table:

```
Name        Value      Sequence    
-------------------------------    
test        A1         1           
test        A2         3           
test2       A20        5         
test2       A10        8
```

I am after grouping the Name and get Value+ and Value- like this:

```
Name        Value+         Value-    
-----------------------------------    
test        A1             A2          
test2       A20            A10
```

Rules are:

- The Value from row with lower Sequence  goes to Value+
- The Value from row with higher Sequence goes to Value-
- There are only two rows per name

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution with a crosstab:

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE (
    Name varchar(50),
    Value varchar(50),
    Sequence int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
 ('test'        ,'A1',         1)       
,('test'        ,'A2',         3)       
,('test2'       ,'A20',        5)       
,('test2'       ,'A10',        8);

WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sequence)
    FROM @SampleData
)
SELECT Name, 
    [Value+] = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Value ELSE '' END),
    [Value-] = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Value ELSE '' END)
FROM RankedData
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 3):

With only 2 value per Name:

```
WITH d AS (
    SELECT Name, [value]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sequence) n
    FROM @data
)
SELECT d1.Name, d1.Value As [Value+], d2.Value As [Value-]
FROM d d1 
INNER JOIN d d2 ON d1.Name = d2.Name AND d1.n = 1 AND d2.n = 2
;
```

This should work with any number of value for each name:

```
WITH d AS (
    SELECT Name, [value]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sequence) mn
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sequence DESC) mx
    FROM data
)
SELECT d1.Name, d1.Value As [Value+], d2.Value As [Value-]
FROM d d1 
INNER JOIN d d2 ON d1.Name = d2.Name AND d1.mn = 1 AND d2.mx = 1
;
```

Sample data:

```
declare @data table
    (Name varchar(5), Value varchar(3), Sequence int)
;

INSERT INTO @data
    (Name, [value], Sequence)
VALUES
    ('test', 'A1', 1),
    ('test', 'A2', 3),
    ('test2', 'A20', 5),
    ('test2', 'A10', 8)
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using SQL Server 2000 or earlier version, you can also do this with [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH ranked AS
  (
    SELECT
      Name,
      Value,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Sequence)
    FROM
      dbo.atable
  )
SELECT
  Name,
  [Value+] = [1],
  [Value-] = [2]
FROM
  ranked
  PIVOT (MIN(Value) FOR RN IN ([1], [2])) AS p
;
```

This is essentially equivalent to [@spaghettidba's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132484/6965), just uses different syntax.

Here is how the query works. The `ranked` CTE evaluates to this row set:

```
Name   Value  RN
-----  -----  --
test   A1     1
test   A2     2
test2  A20    1
test2  A10    2
```

As you can see it gives the ranking of 1 to each row with the lower `Sequence` per `Name`, and ranking of 2 to that with the higher `Sequence`.

The main query's PIVOT clause turns the above into this row set:

```
Name   1    2
-----  ---  ---
test   A1   A2
test2  A20  A10
```

As the result of the pivoting, `Value`s are divided into columns whose names are derived from the `RN` column.

And the SELECT clause of the main query simply renames columns `1` and `2` to `Values+` and `Values-`, respectively, to give you the desired output.

Comment: Why do you need `MIN` here? Or rather, what is it doing in the pivot statement?

Comment: @fraxture: The [`PIVOT` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) requires that you use an aggregate function on the pivoted column. In this case there's no need to aggregate anything really, so we just need to choose an aggregate function that will return the column value unchanged. Both `MIN` and `MAX` work equally well for that. I chose `MIN`. By the way, it's the same with spaghettidba's pivoting technique. It uses `MAX`, but you could replace it with `MIN` and the results would be the same.